# Spark: How to import python files successfully on yarn

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I meet problems when I run `spark-submit` with import my own python files.

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--verbose \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--executor-memory 8g \
--driver-memory 10g \
--num-executors 100 \
--executor-cores 10 \
--py-files dgs://user/tmp/dependency.zip \
test.py
```

I have two python files `data.py` and `proccess.py` in `dependency` folder. Then I `zip -r dependency.zip dependency/` and get `dependency.zip`.

Here is my `test.py`,

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
from data import get_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data()
    distData = sc.parallelize(data)
    print("done",distData.collect())
```

In `data.py`,

```
def get_data():
    return [1,2,3,4,5]
```

But I meet error. `No module named data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `dependency` a module (by putting empty *init*.py file) and import `data` as `from dependency import data`. It should work.